# How to call method for bind property

Tags: javafx, model-binding

I know how to bind a property, but how can I bind the call of a fuction?

For example: I have a `ObjectProperty` which points to a file. Now, I want to bind the path to its folder? If the value of `ObjectProperty` is `C:\\user\Desktop\text.txt`, the bonding should point to `C:\\user\Desktop`.

I thought I can call `getParentFile()` within the binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There a many ways to map an `ObjectProperty`, take a look at the class [`Bindings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html).

(All examples assume that you have a `ObjectProperty<File> file`)

1. [`Bindings.createObjectBinding(Callable<T> func, Observable... dependencies)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#createObjectBinding-java.util.concurrent.Callable-javafx.beans.Observable...-)

   ```
   ObjectBinding<File> parent = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> {
       File f = file.getValue();
       return f == null ? null : f.getParentFile();
   }, file);
   ```
2. [`Bindings.select(ObservableValue<?> root, String... steps)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#select-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-java.lang.String...-)

   ```
   ObjectBinding<File> parent = Bindings.select(file, "parentFile");
   ```

   This will print a warning on the error-stream when `file` is null.

You can also create your own mapping method (which is similar to `createObjectBinding`):

```
public static <T,R> ObjectBinding<R> map(ObjectProperty<T> property, Function<T,R> function) {
    return new ObjectBinding<R>() {
        {
            bind(property);
        }
        @Override
        protected R computeValue() {
            return function.apply(property.getValue());
        }
        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            unbind(property);
        }
    };
}
```

And use it

```
ObjectBinding<File> parent = map(file, f -> f == null ? null : f.getParentFile());
```